In Python, how do I iterate a long path name through glob and read in all files in Windows?
I'm trying to write a Python script where I use glob to get a list of file paths, and then read them through pd.read_csv() to make one big data frame. This script works great on a Mac. However, I was trying to help a colleague run this in Jupyter Notebook on their PC, and it kept failing.
The Mac script is simple. It's just:
df = pd.DataFrame()

subfolders = ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3']

for sub in subfolders:
        for filePath in glob.glob('/server/folder1/folder2/'+sub+'/*/*/*/*/*/*/lastfolder/*output.txt'):
                df2 = pd.read_csv(filePath, sep='\t')
                df = pd.concat([df, df2])

They've run similar scripts in the past with no problem. However, this path length is now greater than >260 characters, which I think caused the problem.
For long paths, Windows adds a bit to the front (...for reasons?) like:
\?\UNC\server\share\directory...
When I tried to read in a path with that additional "\?\UNC" part, it breaks things. Normally I tell them just to change the backslashes to forward slashes, but that doesn't work here (I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this really isn't a big part of my job--I'm just trying to get things to run more efficiently).
I don't really know how to deal with Windows, so every time I try to help them it's an adventure. I tried to ask ChatGPT, and it led me to this solution:
# Define the UNC path with the long path prefix
long_unc_path = r'\\?\UNC\server\folder1\folder2\'


# Convert the long UNC path to a Path object
new_path = Path(long_unc_path)

df = pd.DataFrame()

subfolders = ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3']

for sub in subfolders:
        for filePath in glob.glob(new_path+sub+'/*/*/*/*/*/*/lastfolder/*output.txt'):
                df2 = pd.read_csv(filePath, sep='\t')
                df = pd.concat([df, df2])

But the first line for long_unc_path gave me an unterminated string literal error. I'm sure it's a simple solution, but I can't figure out what it is. We're using Python 3.11.
Could anyone help? Thank you!

Discard '\' at the end of the long_unc_path  and use os.path.join to create file address instead of adding strings, something like this
import os
import re

# Define the UNC path with the long path prefix
long_unc_path = r'\\?\UNC\server\folder1\folder2'


# Convert the long UNC path to a Path object
new_path = Path(long_unc_path)

df = pd.DataFrame()

subfolders = ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3']

for sub in subfolders:
        for filePath in glob.glob(os.path.join(new_path,sub,*re.split('/', '/*/*/*/*/*/*/lastfolder/*output.txt'))):
                df2 = pd.read_csv(filePath, sep='\t')
                df = pd.concat([df, df2])


This is because raw strings are not completely raw as you think and they can cause unterminated string literal error. In you case the last \ at the end of the string tries to act as an escape character and escape '. So it does not find the end of the string and causes the problem. If it is necessary to have \ at the end of the string, you can define it as normal string and add it to the end of the path :
long_unc_path = r'\\?\UNC\server\folder1\folder2' +'\\'


I will try to follow-up with them next week and see if this works. Thank you for your help!

This still gave me an error, but the other solution worked. Thank you!
